# Movie about people trapped in a building where the exit keeps on moving or disappearing

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm desperately looking for a movie name. It's about a group of people locked or trapped in a building overnight. The exit keeps on changing or disappearing and time stops or freezes, (one old man closed the door in the evening and it was open again the next morning). They entered the building of their own will to stay overnight. The building was large, maybe a factory, school, or hospital (I can't  remember). All throughout the movie they are trying to find the exit.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this movie?  Why didn't they leave through the door that the old man opened?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what was the makeup of this group (teens, elderly people, men, women)?, what language was the film in? What were the character's names? Was this an adult film (with sex and violence and horror elements) or something for children? Were there any actors you recognised? Was this film in colour or black-and-white? When do you think it was made? Was it a big budget film or something cheap and nasty?

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=trapped-in-a-building / https://bestsimilar.com/tag/1602-trapped-in-a-building

Comment: The title made me think of "Cube", but it doesn't fit the longer description.

Answer (score 3):

It has to be [Grave Encounters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_Encounters)!

The description reads

> The crew of a paranormal reality television program lock themselves in a supposedly haunted psychiatric hospital in search of evidence of paranormal activity, as they shoot what ends up becoming their final episode.